# Dynamically put table in clipboard javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to dynamically create a table in javascript and put it in clipboard as a table. Like that when we paste the value in email or word document, it will automatically display as a table.

I am using this code to put the data in clipboard (it is available on [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/UwGCQSh4q8ZT5SkHQOYk?p=preview))

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var data = [
    {lastName:'Doe', firstName:'John', birthday: '01.01.2001'},
    {lastName:'Doe', firstName:'Jane', birthday: '02.02.2002'},
    {lastName:'Foo', firstName:'Bar', birthday: '03.03.2003'}
    ];

  var exportResult = '<table><tr><th> Last name</th><th> First name</th><th> Birthday </th></tr>';

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    exportResult += '<tr><td>' + data[i].lastName + '</td><td>' + data[i].lastName + '</td><td>' + data[i].lastName + '</td></tr>'
  }

  exportResult += '</table>';

  $("button").click(function(){
    var textarea =  '<textarea>' + exportResult + '</textarea>';
    $("body").append(textarea);
    $("textarea").select();

    try {
        var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
        if (!successful) throw successful;
    } catch (err) {
        window.prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", toCopy);
    }

    $("textarea").remove();
  });
});
```

But when I past it in word doc or in email, this is raw plain text and not html table.

Answer (score 0):

This code works :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var data = [
    {lastName:'Doe', firstName:'John', birthday: '01.01.2001'},
    {lastName:'Doe', firstName:'Jane', birthday: '02.02.2002'},
    {lastName:'Foo', firstName:'Bar', birthday: '03.03.2003'}
    ];

  var exportResult = '<table id="tableToCopy"><tr>' +
                     '<th> Last name</th>' +
                     '<th> First name</th>' +
                     '<th> Birthday </th>' +
                     '</tr>';

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    exportResult += '<tr>' +
                    '<td>' + data[i].lastName + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + data[i].lastName + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + data[i].lastName + '</td>' +
                    '</tr>'
  }

  exportResult += '</table>';

  $("button").click(function(){
    $("body").append(exportResult);

    var body = document.body, range, sel, el= document.getElementById('tableToCopy');
    if (document.createRange && window.getSelection) {
      range = document.createRange();
      sel = window.getSelection();
      sel.removeAllRanges();
      try {
        range.selectNodeContents(el);
        sel.addRange(range);
      } catch (e) {
        range.selectNode(el);
        sel.addRange(range);
      }
      } else if (body.createTextRange) {
        range = body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(el);
        range.select();
        range.execCommand("Copy");
      }
      document.execCommand('copy');
      $("table").remove();}
  );
});
```